# Is Armus aka 'Skin of Evil' related to the Ba'ul species?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-discovery

In season 2, episode 6 'The Sound of Thunder' of *Star Trek: Discovery* we learn a few things about the Ba'ul.

> Their appearance is very similar to the one of Armus in ST:TNG 'Skin of Evil'.

So the obvious question is if they are related in some way?

Comment: does this need a spoiler tag?

Comment: This is called Small Universe Thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely. Armus' people (before they ditched him for being a meany-pants) were apparently godlike Adonises.

> **ARMUS** [OC]: *I am alone.*
>
> **TROI:** *Abandoned. Who deserted you?*
>
> **ARMUS** [OC]: ***Creatures whose beauty now dazzles all who see them.** They would not exist without me.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Skin of Evil - Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/122.htm)</sup></sub>

The Ba'ul, by comparison look like the offspring of a oilspill and a slightly uglier oilspill.

Comment: +1 : Armus was the result of something an alien race did, casting off their base nature, not the race itself "They perfected a means of bringing to the surface all that was evil and negative within. Erupting, spreading, connecting. In time it formed second skin, dank and vile. "

Comment: I agree with your answer, but: Wouldn't Armus, in all his evil, selfishness, and vice, see _himself_ as dazzlingly beautiful?

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - No. He sees himself as "dank and vile". **ARMUS:** *They perfected a means of bringing to the surface all that was evil and negative within. Erupting, spreading, connecting. In time it formed second skin, dank and vile.* 
**TROI:** *You.* **ARMUS:** *Yes.*

Comment: Welp, so much for jokes here on SFF...

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - I already done made a joke in my answer,